# Angular JS - Error: ng:areq Bad Argument Argument 'GameContoller' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm just trying to link up my "GameController" in Angular and it keeps spitting out this error above. Haven't put anything in the scope yet but I'm not sure what's wrong with my controller. Any suggestions? It's for a basic Tic Tac Toe game.

JS:

```
// module
var xoxoApp = angular.module('xoxoApp', []); 

// defines controller
xoxoApp.controller('GameController', function ($scope) {  
    $scope.boxes = []
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="xoxoApp">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="xoxo.css">

<script src="angular.min.js"></script>  

<script src="xoxo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>

</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="GameContoller">
    <div id="container">

        <div class= "squares" id="box1" onclick="clickBox('box1')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box2" onclick="clickBox('box2')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box3" onclick="clickBox('box3')"></div>

        <div class= "squares" id="box4" onclick="clickBox('box4')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box5" onclick="clickBox('box5')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box6" onclick="clickBox('box6')"></div>

        <div class= "squares" id="box7" onclick="clickBox('box7')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box8" onclick="clickBox('box8')"></div>
        <div class= "squares" id="box9" onclick="clickBox('box9')"></div>

    </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be that you misspelled `GameController`?

Comment: It could definitely be. I love it when I waste hours on something like that. Thanks, it works.

Comment: @user3802738 I can relate, sometimes you just need another set of eyes :)